# JPA OneToMany collection returned as Empty

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

Doing a lookup of a previously saved 1-to-many entity. Entitles are:

Book.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="book", orphanRemoval=true)
    private Collection<Author> authors;

    public Collection<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }
        ...

        @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + ", authors=" + authors + ", title=" + title
                + ", isbn=" + isbn + "]";
    }
}
```

Author.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Authors")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
    private Book book;

        ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "Author [id=" + id + ", book=" + book + ", firstName="
            + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }
}
```

Ignoring the dubious cardinality of the data model, the lookup code is

```
long bookID = 10; // saved entity ID
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
Book savedBook = entityManager.find(Book.class, bookID);
System.out.println("Book " + savedBook);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

which gives the output

```
Book Book [id=10, authors=[], title=Treasure Island, isbn=123456]
```

Any ideas why authors is empty?

---

```
Retrieving 11...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:240)
    at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:100)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2946)
    at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:733)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at org.hibstore.domain.Book.toString(Book.java:64)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at org.hibstore.domain.Author.toString(Author.java:67)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:501)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at org.hibstore.domain.Book.toString(Book.java:64)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
```

Comment: You may need to explicitly call the `getAuthors()` on book before you try to print.

Comment: Tried that, didnt work :(

Comment: See the queries generated by JPA and ensure the child queries are firing and you have the child records in DB. Hope you already have tried that option, but everything else is looking fine here.

Comment: DB is being populated but, one thing - the join field content is `null` in the database...The funny thing is that the `List` is populated if I do a lookup immediately after I save the entity. But is empty once I fire up a new client with above code

Comment: Then the problem might be while inserting the records. You need to set parent to child and add child to parent like `book.addAuthor(author); and author.setBook(book)` as the child is driving the relationship here.

Comment: The error you mentioned is because the `toString()` methods. Dont call book's toString() from `Author`. Its going into recursive loop. Just call book.getId() in Author's toString()

Comment: Already fixed it b4 you updated but thanks nonetheless :)) Your `author.setBook` suggestion worked. Make it an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be while inserting the records. 
You need to set parent to child and add child to parent like `book.addAuthor(author);` and `author.setBook(book)` as the child is driving the relationship here.

Comment: I don't understand how this is. Could you tell me what is happening in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem could have been to set the Entity Author > book field mapping of @ManyToOne to `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`

Comment: Tried this, didnt work, thanks for your answer though :)